# array into hash ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have such array in ruby (document language [even index] and number of words [odd index])

```
words = ["en",200,"ru","120","es",140,"ru",240]
```

Final result should look like:

```
{"en"=>200,"ru=>360","es"=>140}
```

Comment: Why is `'120'` a `String` but the other numbers are `Fixnum`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, you need to sum duplicate keys. So, the `Hash::[]` method won't work here. No problem, use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) + [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) then:

```
words = ["en",200,"ru","120","es",140,"ru",240]

hash = words.each_slice(2).each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), memo|
  memo[k] ||= 0
  memo[k] += v.to_i
end

hash # => {"en"=>200, "ru"=>360, "es"=>140}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to first slice the array into chunks and then add the values.

This is version which is roughly equivalent to the one by Sergio Tulentsev but is a bit shorter (and works in Ruby 1.8).

```
hash = words.each_slice(2).inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, (k, v)|
  hash[k] += v.to_i
  hash
end
```

Note that I initialize the hash with a default value of 0. Sergio could have done the same, so that his version would look like this:

```
hash = words.each_slice(2).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k, v), memo|
  memo[k] += v.to_i
end
```

Note that `each_with_object` as used by Sergio was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and is thus not available in older Ruby versions, which might not by an issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['en', 200, 'ru', 120, 'es', 140, 'ru', 240]

words.
 each_slice(2).
 each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(lang, wordcount), acc| acc[lang] += wordcount }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
words = ["en",200,"ru","120","es",140,"ru",240]

h1 = Hash[*words.flatten]
```

Comment: This doesn't produce desired result